# What is the best way to redirect pc website to mobile version

Tags: redirect, mobile, web

I have create a mobile version of my website and i want to redirect from pc to mobile version if user using a mobile. I found few things but let me know what is the best way. It should view any mobile or tablet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used [detect mobile browsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) with good success. It has lots of downloadable script options like .htaccess for an apache server, php script, jQuery, perl and plenty of others.

It's a good starting point.

Good luck!